# use cv2.VideoCapture to capture a picture

Tags: python, opencv

I want to use my laptop webcam to capture a picture using the code below:

```py
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()


cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

but it throws this error:

> cv2.imshow('frame', frame) cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0)
>   C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:350:
>   error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in
>   function 'cv::imshow'

How can I fix this error?

Comment: always check `ret` - result status. If OpenCV has problem to get value from camera then it doesn't raise error but it return `False` in `ret` and it may have `None` in `frame` and later `imshow` may have problem to display `None`

Comment: as I remeber laptop webcamera has number `0` (zero), not `1`

Answer (score 1):

When `OpenCV` has problem to get frame from camera or stream then it doesn't raise error but it return `False` in `ret` (return status) so you should check it. It also return `None` in `frame` and `imshow` has problem to display `None` - it has no width and height - so you get error with `size.width>0 && size.height>0`

As I know mostly laptop webcame has number `0`, not `1`

This works with my laptop webcam

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # zero instead of one

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if not ret: # exit loop if there was problem to get frame to display
        break

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

**EDIT:** as said Dave W. Smith in comment: some laptops may need time to send correct image then here version which doesn't exit loop

```
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if ret: # display only if status (ret) is True and there is frame
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

Comment: The `break` may be overly aggressive. On an older Thinkpad, the first few attempts to capture an image would fail. I recommend throwing in a counter.

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  #it can be one also...but generally zero

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('Capture', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Try this one...it works for mine...make sure numpy is installed

Comment: Please, can you extend your answer with more detailed explanation? This will be very useful for understanding. Thank you!

Comment: cv2.VideoCapture()  captures the live feed from webcam...cap.read() will read the feed frame by frame and imshow displays the output...this happens repeated beacuse of the while loop...and if 'q' is pressed..then the loop stops....and finally if the camera stops cap.release() closes the window and cv2.destroyAllWindows does the job of killing the program