# Error in OpenCV code: cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1)

Tags: python, opencv

I am writing a code in python using the OpenCV Python library.

I wanted to access the webcam using the code written, but after executing the code in the terminal, the following error arises again and again.

Code written:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
    break

cap.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Error:

[image: Code error]

Comment: look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56197011/use-cv2-videocapture-to-capture-a-picture

Comment: You're welcome.  Happy coding!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [use cv2.VideoCapture to capture a picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56197011/use-cv2-videocapture-to-capture-a-picture)

Answer (score 0):

If this is a camera installed on your computer:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

    cap.release()

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

If this is a camera connected via USB:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

    cap.release()

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```